# Can you dynamically assign CFBundleDocumentTypes (with private API?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, cfbundledocumenttypes

I'm trying to add additional 'Open In' feature to an existing app. I found a way to add the necessary `CFBundleDocumentTypes` to the Info.plist within the application bundle. Now my only problem is having the iOS register this key to allow 'Open In' from other apps. I assumed after a reboot iOS would check all installed app's Info.plist files and register `CFBundleDocumentTypes` on load. This is not the case. It seems if I create an IPA with the edited Info.plist & install it on my device, 'Open In' is registered automatically throughout the iOS.

I've read here with not much help. [Can you dynamically assign CFBundleDocumentTypes to your Cocoa application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542022/can-you-dynamically-assign-cfbundledocumenttypes-to-your-cocoa-application)

I checked in the `/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.mobile.installation.plist` 
I noticed that some keys that are in the `Info.plist` are in the `com.mobile.installation.plist`

For instance; `UIDeviceFamily, UIBackgroundModes, UIRequiredDeviceCapibilities` but no `CFBundleDocumentTypes`

Does anyone know where else I could look? There has gotta be way to do this with private frameworks. (Since this is for jailbroken development)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a bit of a hack to reload the `CFBundleDocumentTypes`

If you can get access, delete the file:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.LaunchServices-054.csstore
```

Then tell the user to reboot, if a respring is done instead you'll have delete the file & reboot again. (Since the `com.apple.LaunchServices-054.csstore` file returns after a respring.)

Hope this helps someone in the Jailbreak community if they manage to stumble across.

Note, I think this method only works on iOS7. :(